# OCaml: How to generate permutations until a certain condition?

Tags: ocaml, permutation

Still learning more about OCaml here, but I'm working on a method that takes a compares two list of strings in OCaml. The first list is a list of strings that will be compared. The second list will then be a string that may or may not be a word, but must generate permutations until it creates a word that exists in the first list. For example,

List 1:`["hello"; "there"]`
List 2:`["hlleo"]`

List 2 should generate permutations until it matches a string in List 1. I cannot seem to create a condition that makes it stop generating permutations when needed nor can I get the right types. I've looked all over and while I can generate permutations, it does not exactly do what I need and I am at a loss. This is what I have so far:

```
let rec implode : char list -> string = function
  | []    -> ""
  | c::cs -> String.make 1 c ^ implode cs

let is_word_in word lst = List.mem word lst

let rec interleave x lst = 
  match lst with
  | [] -> [[x]]
  | hd::tl -> (x::lst) :: (List.map (fun y -> hd::y) (interleave x tl))

let rec permutations str lst accum= 
  match str with
  | hd::tl -> let perm = List.concat (List.map (interleave hd) (permutations tl lst)) in 
    if is_word_in (implode(perm)) lst then (implode(perm))::accum else perm
  | _ -> [str]
```

Any form of help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: If you just want to know whether some permutation of a string `s` exists in your first list, a much faster way is to order the characters of each string of the first list into a known order. Then order the characters of `s` and do one test for membership in the list of reordered strings. There is no need to generate permutations.

Comment: Wow, im not sure why i didn't even think of this. Thank you so much!! This saves my program a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I would try to do, in order to split the task into smaller, easier tasks.

1. write `permutations` to only print each permutation, and do nothing else
2. test if this works correctly
3. instead of printing permutations, add a new parameter F, a function that accepts a permutation and return true or false; when the returned value is false, stop generating permutations; you need to let this information bubble up the recursive calls (`permutations` also returns a boolean)
4. Rewrite to use an option type, instead of a boolean; stop iterating on `None` values. In other words, function F can return either `None` or `Some 'a`, but you don't need to handle the `Some` case for now.
5. Add a parameter A, the accumulator, of type `'a`. Call F with both the accumulator and the permutation. F returns
   *Some* new accumulator or *None*. The return type of `permutations` is `'a option` too.
6. You can write a function that checks if a palindrome matches some condition, and stop iteration at this point. But notice that when you stop iterating, the current value of the accumulator is not returned. How you can return the accumulator in case of an early exit?